# PWA update service worker when app is already loaded

Tags: javascript, updates, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA and I'm looking for a way to update a service worker when the app is already open and loaded.

For example the user opens the app once on his phone and then switches through other apps during the day without completely closing the PWA.

If I upload a new version in between, how can the service worker then be updated?

And also is there maybe a way to notify the service about an update while the user is using the App?

Is the service worker able to automatically check from time to time if something new was uploaded? The whole app is cached and served from a s3 bucket.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: a really good quesiton.. I must say

Comment: @Richardson it's been a while but if I remember correctly I ended up notifying the application server when releasing a new client version. When the user then came back, the client was notified that a new version is available with the next fetch. I don't remember if I fetched the info on page focus or just checked on the next best fetch though. If versions differed I notified the user and either reloaded the page or called in the SW update, can't remember. But it was something like that. Don't know if there is a better solution for that meanwhile cause it felt a bit like much overhead.

Comment: actually i came to this conclusion sine each client node is an isolated environment and the client sw wont now if there is a a new update... could you check my question if you have time if you could guide my flow ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742712/is-there-any-way-to-force-new-service-worker-cache-version-update-during-app-run

Comment: I just want to force mandatory updates.

Answer (score 2):

From MDN on ["ServiceWorkerRegistration.update()
"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update).

> The update method of the ServiceWorkerRegistration interface attempts to update the service worker. It fetches the worker's script URL, and if the new worker is not byte-by-byte identical to the current worker, it installs the new worker. The fetch of the worker bypasses any browser caches if the previous fetch occurred over 24 hours ago.

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw-test/sw.js', {scope: 'sw-test'}).then(function(registration) {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded.');
    button.onclick = function() {
      registration.update();
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
};
```